# Can't set SQL parameter value to a string array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to pass an array of strings as a SQL parameter, but when I execute the command, it throws an exception that says "Object must implement IConvertible".  Here is the code (all three columns are nvarchar):

```
Public Sub sendsms(messageBodies As String(), ByVal recipientNumbers As String(), Optional ByVal chkMsgIds As string() = Nothing) 
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = connection.Sms
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into sentmessage (text,id,number) values (@text,@id,@number)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, n).Value = messageBodies 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, n).Value = chkMsgIds
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, n).Value = recipientNumbers
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I created this routine to insert huge amounts of records into the database, what is correct approach?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  Did you want all the elements of the array to be combined into a single one line string, or delimited with comas, or made into a multi-line string with one array item per line?

Comment: how should i insert huge numbers of records to sql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would just execute multiple insert commands, one per row, such as:

```
Public Sub sendsms(messageBodies As String(), ByVal recipientNumbers As String(), Optional ByVal chkMsgIds As string() = Nothing) 
    Using con As New SqlConnection()
        con.ConnectionString = connection.Sms
        con.Open()
        For Each body As String In messageBodies
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into sentmessage (text,id,number) values (@text,@id,@number)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@text", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, n).Value = body
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, n).Value = chkMsgIds
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, n).Value = recipientNumbers
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

However, in SQL Server 2008, they added support for a new multi-row insert syntax which is explained here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/

For instance, you could execute a command such as:

```
insert into sentmessage (text,id,number) values 
('First',1,1),
('Second',2,2),
('Third',3,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", messageBodies )
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",chkMsgIds)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", recipientNumbers)
```